# PuTTY outputs weird stuff when selecting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, output, putty

I've encountered a strange problem when I was using PuTTY to query the following MySQL command: `select * from gts_camera`

The output seems extremely weird: [image]

As you can see, putty outputs loads of "PuTTYPuTTYPuTTY..."

Maybe it's because of the table attribute set:

```
    mysql> describe gts_kamera;
+---------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| datum   | datetime | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| picture | longblob | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

This table stores some big pictures and their date of creation.
(The weird ASCII-characters you can see on top of the picture is the content.)

Does anybody know why PuTTY outputs such strange stuff, and how to solve/clean this?

Cause I can't type any other commands afterwards. I have to reopen the session again.

Sincerely,
Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is because of the contents of the file (as you have a column defined with `longblob`). It may have some characters that Putty will not understand, therefore it will break as it is happening with you.

There is a configuration that may help though.
[image]

You can also not select every column in that table (at least not the `*blob` ones) as:

```
select id, datum from gts_camera;
```

Or If you still want to do it use the MySql funtion [HEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_hex):

```
select id, datum, HEX(picture) as pic from gts_camera;
```

Comment: Thank you! The `HEX(picture) as pic`  made it!